# Reading the LogCat and some other questions

Tags: android

I have two questions (actually, three). And they are also unrelated!

1. What does the given LogCat say? What's wrong with my code? I am new to Android development and I can't read it properly. 
   I want to get some idea on What those errors are and what causes them?
2. How do you read the LogCat? Do you read it from the start? And do you start understanding and fixing the errors starting from the first one and working through to the last one?
3. I started learning Android development and have been reading (and practicing) stuff from developers.android.com.
   I read (and practiced) about Activities, something about Intents and Intent filters, got an overview (read and practiced the basics) of processes and threads, and the manifest file as well.
   But the thing is that whichever program I write, it doesn't behave properly.
   I get lots of exceptions, and almost every app crashes.
   I am talking about simple apps.
   Therefore, I understand I don't have a grip on basics.
   So I searched and got this book named "Hello Android".
   Will you suggest me to read the book from the start?

LOGCAT:-

```
11-30 05:56:03.357: I/System.out(1018): Start
11-30 05:56:03.597: D/libEGL(1018): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-30 05:56:03.637: D/(1018): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1c4c88, tid 1018
11-30 05:56:03.657: D/libEGL(1018): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-30 05:56:03.667: D/libEGL(1018): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-30 05:56:03.777: W/EGL_emulation(1018): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-30 05:56:03.817: D/OpenGLRenderer(1018): Enabling debug mode 0
11-30 05:56:04.987: D/dalvikvm(1018): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 343K, 14% free 2654K/3080K, paused 44ms, total 47ms
11-30 05:56:05.047: I/System.out(1018): Error
11-30 05:56:05.057: W/System.err(1018): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-30 05:56:05.157: W/System.err(1018):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
11-30 05:56:05.157: W/System.err(1018):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:837)
11-30 05:56:05.178: W/System.err(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-30 05:56:05.178: W/System.err(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-30 05:56:05.178: W/System.err(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-30 05:56:05.188: W/System.err(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-30 05:56:05.188: W/System.err(1018):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:358)
11-30 05:56:05.188: W/System.err(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-30 05:56:05.198: W/System.err(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6524)
11-30 05:56:05.207: W/System.err(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3771)
11-30 05:56:05.207: W/System.err(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
11-30 05:56:05.207: W/System.err(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
11-30 05:56:05.217: W/System.err(1018):     at com.example.tutorialksoap21.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:43)
11-30 05:56:05.217: W/System.err(1018):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to read the first line of your error. Your exception is CalledFromWrongThreadException. Its name is pretty clear. You tried to set a Text in a Thread different that the main thread.
2. On your LogCat, you should read the level. W means warning, so you need to read it first. The priority is :

   - Assert
   - Error
   - Warning
   - Information
   - Debug
   - Verbose

   In most of cases, Warning or above means something not expected occurred.

   About your exception, you have the first line with the exception explicated, on the second line, the method in which this exception occurred, on the third line, the method that called the one of the second line and so on.

   It's for example by reading those lines that I know you tried to set a text in a different Thread.

   I know that you run a different Thread with the line `com.example.tutorialksoap21.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:43)`

   And I know in it you tried to set a text with the line just above `android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)`
3. For the third question, no answer, referring to How To of Stack Overflow for asking questions :

   > We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.